# Lubuntu 20.04 laptop suddenly lost the internal screen, and the font is tiny on an external one

Tags: nvidia, lubuntu, multiple-monitors, scaling, lxqt

Usually, a screen suddenly going out means that the backlight has died.  **But that's not the case here.**  This is a dual-boot machine, and the internal screen is perfectly okay during POST, GRUB, and in Windows 10.  So it's not the backlight, and I'm pretty sure it's not anything hardware related.

This is a Dell M6800 with two graphics cards: a low-power Intel thing, and a Quadro K5100M.  The NVIDIA X Server Settings GUI reports a single screen (the external one) running at 1920x1080x60Hz, just like LXQt's Monitor Settings does.  A handful of apps seem to be readable enough - NVIDIA X Server and Firefox for example, which is how I'm writing this - but the text for most things is just a couple of blurry pixels tall, including the terminal.  If I'm making it out out correctly, LXQt's Appearance Configuration still has the font size at 11pt and the DPI at 96.

I just updated about an hour ago - sudo apt [update|full-upgrade|autoremove] - got a few, and rebooted, with no change.

Any idea what's causing this?  And how to get the internal screen back with a decent system font?

---

Compiled from chat:

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log` is:
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/24tSjCHdmW/

```
aaron@aaron-Lubuntu:~$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 1
 0: +DP-0 1920/1150x1080/650+0+0  DP-0
aaron@aaron-Lubuntu:~$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x2d8 cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 8 associated providers: 0 name:NVIDIA-0
aaron@aaron-Lubuntu:~$
aaron@aaron-Lubuntu:~$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL

Command 'glxinfo' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install mesa-utils

aaron@aaron-Lubuntu:~$ sudo apt install mesa-utils
[sudo] password for aaron:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mesa-utils
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 34.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 150 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 mesa-utils amd64 8.4.0-1build1 [34.2 kB]
Fetched 34.2 kB in 1s (40.3 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package mesa-utils.
(Reading database ... 296803 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mesa-utils_8.4.0-1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-utils (8.4.0-1build1) ...
Setting up mesa-utils (8.4.0-1build1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
aaron@aaron-Lubuntu:~$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: Quadro K5100M/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 470.103.01
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 470.103.01
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 470.103.01
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
aaron@aaron-Lubuntu:~$ sudo apt install nvidia-prime
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-prime is already the newest version (0.8.16~0.20.04.1).
nvidia-prime set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
aaron@aaron-Lubuntu:~$
aaron@aaron-Lubuntu:~$ cat ./.bash_history | grep nvidia
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430
aaron@aaron-Lubuntu:~$
aaron@aaron-Lubuntu:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d4)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev d4)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104GLM [Quadro K5100M] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev bb)
11:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
aaron@aaron-Lubuntu:~$ lshw -C video
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK104GLM [Quadro K5100M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:39 memory:f4000000-f4ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
aaron@aaron-Lubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -C video
[sudo] password for aaron:
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK104GLM [Quadro K5100M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:39 memory:f4000000-f4ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
aaron@aaron-Lubuntu:~$ apt policy xserver-xorg-video-intel
xserver-xorg-video-intel:
  Installed: 2:2.99.917+git20200226-1
  Candidate: 2:2.99.917+git20200226-1
  Version table:
 *** 2:2.99.917+git20200226-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
aaron@aaron-Lubuntu:~$
aaron@aaron-Lubuntu:~$ dpkg -l | grep mesa
ii  libegl-mesa0:amd64                            21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2           amd64        free implementation of the EGL API -- Mesa vendor library
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64                         21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2           amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386                          21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2           i386         free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libglapi-mesa:amd64                           21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2           amd64        free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libglapi-mesa:i386                            21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2           i386         free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libglu1-mesa:amd64                            9.0.1-1build1                       amd64        Mesa OpenGL utility library (GLU)
ii  libglx-mesa0:amd64                            21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2           amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX vendor library
ii  libglx-mesa0:i386                             21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2           i386         free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX vendor library
ii  mesa-utils                                    8.4.0-1build1                       amd64        Miscellaneous Mesa GL utilities
ii  mesa-va-drivers:amd64                         21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2           amd64        Mesa VA-API video acceleration drivers
ii  mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64                      21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2           amd64        Mesa VDPAU video acceleration drivers
ii  mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64                     21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2           amd64        Mesa Vulkan graphics drivers
ii  mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386                      21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2           i386         Mesa Vulkan graphics drivers
aaron@aaron-Lubuntu:~$ prime-select query
nvidia
aaron@aaron-Lubuntu:~$
```

For comparison, a live USB has this in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`:
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/GDDhPjFTCv/
and:

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 2
 0: +eDP-1 1920/382x1080/215+0+0  eDP-1
 1: +DP-3 1920/708x1080/398+1920+0  DP-3
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x48 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 5 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135064/discussion-on-question-by-aarond-lubuntu-20-04-laptop-suddenly-lost-the-internal).

Comment: I'm writing this here for visibility and because I think this advice may help others with the same problem, but if you wish to answer further, feel free to use the chat: I'm out of ideas. It seems your installation is all fine, except the system simply refuses to see your Intel GPU. Since it is working on a live system and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is coming in about 3 weeks, maybe that's a good opportunity to install a fresh system where everything will be working. I personally do that every 2 years anyway, experience shows it can be less troublesome then updating an existing system. :) Best of luck!

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa I was wondering about doing that anyway.  Also switching to UbuntuStudio because I've been doing a bunch of media-related stuff lately and expect to continue that.  So I was already looking for a release date for UbuntuStudio 22.04 LTS, and then this happened.  It's still far enough out that I thought it might still be worth finding a fix, but that equation is changing kinda fast now.  Thanks for trying anyway!